Does the proportion A/(A+B) decreases if A decreases faster than B?
True or False.
Let $f(x) = \frac{a(x)}{a(x) + b(x)}$ and $a(x),b(x) >0$ $\forall x$.
If $a'(x) < b'(x)$ $\forall x$ then $f'(x)<0$.
I started out with this problem thinking that it was obviously true, but after I take a derivative I seem to require more conditions. Would like to get any insights on this. Thanks

Should the domain of $a$ and $b$ be real numbers ? Are we allowed to consider functions with domain as a proper subset of real numbers ?

Yes, the domain of $a$ and $b$ are real numbers and we can consider any subset of the reals.

Consider $a : (0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$ and $b : (0, \infty)\to \mathbb{R}$, given by
$$a: x\mapsto x\\~~ b: x\mapsto2x$$
Then $\forall x\in (0,\infty),~ f(x)=\frac{1}{3}$.

Thank you, I wonder what the intuition was telling me, gotta think about it more. I guess switching $a$ and $b$ is more accurate but the insight still stands.

But we need $b'(x)>a'(x)$ right ?

Yes, you are correct- my bad.

What you really need is that the relative growth is more: $a^\prime/a<b^\prime/b$. Note
$$\left(\frac{a}{a+b}\right)^\prime=\frac{ab\left(\frac{a^\prime}{a}-\frac{b^\prime}{b}\right)}{(a+b)^2}$$
Another way to look at it is:
$$\frac{a}{a+b}=\frac{1}{1+b/a}$$
Note that $t\mapsto1/(1+t)$ is decreasing so $a/(a+b)$ is decreasing if $b/a$ is increasing which means the same thing.
Hope this helps. :)

Thank you, this clears things up for me. :)
